# Can't change color of environment

Tags: pycharm

Here is how my pyCharm 4.5 looks. In settings changing color schema only applies to editor not to menu options. Is there fix? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is covered by the official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/editor-appearance.html).

You can change the color of the IDE by going to the "Preferences", then "Appearance & Behavior", and then selecting a different "Theme" in the dropdown under "UI Options."